# Rails : When encryption used in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, aes

we have a mobile APP and want to embed a PC page,for example: `www.XXX.com`

But we need member has logined in this page.

So we can build this url`www.XXX.com?token=XXXXXXX`

So the token can't be plaintext and must be encrypted,so I use a `aes` gem

I encrypt one member id to `oDk6N21+t26f1PbvwIHtNw==$ZO319ZlmjsOMTzh+sF/hHg==`

So the url turns to be `www.XXX.com?token=oDk6N21+t26f1PbvwIHtNw==$ZO319ZlmjsOMTzh+sF/hHg==`

Now the question is come.

I try to get the `token` value ,but I get `oDk6N21 t26f1PbvwIHtNw==$ZO319ZlmjsOMTzh sF/hHg==`

Some character has been replaced,so how can I get the original `token`?

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be straightforward:

```
# generate random key
key = AES.key

# encrypting your message
encr = AES.encrypt "my message", key

# decrypt later with the same key
AES.decrypt encr, key # => "my message"
```

The full documentation is [here](https://github.com/chicks/aes).